# Measure parallelizability of task scheduler graph in Dask

Tags: parallel-processing, dask, scheduler, scheduling, directed-acyclic-graphs

If I have a large [custom task graph](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/custom-graphs.html) fed into Dask, and a list of times that each task will take (e.g. in the simplest case, each task might take the same number of CPU seconds/minutes), is there a way to calculate how "parallelizable" the problem is from the structure of the graph, without actually running the tasks? The assumption would be that the time to calculate scheduling priorities etc is negligible compared to the time of each task.

I'm thinking of a metric either that plots the number of parallel processes being used over time (assuming an infinite number of available cores), or perhaps the number of hours that the whole graph would take, given a fixed number of CPU cores.

If not, this seems like a nice thing to be able to provide for the task scheduler, especially if individual tasks are expected to take many minutes or hours. However, I guess it might be hard to calculate analytically, depending on the algorithm(s) underlying task allocation in Dask.

Comment: This would indeed be cool metric to have, you don't mention Amdahl's law, so you might find this interesting: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law